# If $G = HN$, $N\unlhd G$, $H\cap N = 1$ - is $G/N \cong H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This might be a stupid question, but right now it does not seem obvious to me if for a finite group $G$ with normal subgroup $N$ and subgroup $H$ such that $G = HN$ -- is it then true that $G/N \cong H$? How does an isomorphism look?

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product)

Comment: $HN/N\cong H/(H\cap N)$ via $hN\mapsto h(H\cap N)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It follows immediately from the isomorphism theorems that $G/N = HN/N \cong H/H \cap N \cong H.$

Comment: How do we know that the intersection $H\cap N$ is trivial?

Comment: Because it was stated in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In fact, under these circumstances $G \cong N \rtimes H$ for some semidirect product of $N$ and $H$. The isomorphism is then the composition of $H \hookrightarrow G \twoheadrightarrow G/N$.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $G=HN$ means precisely that for every $g\in G$ there is a unique pair $(h,n) \in H\times N$ such that $g=hn$, so you can define the projections
$$
\pi_H:G \to H, g=hn \mapsto h,\quad \pi_N:G \to N, g=hn \mapsto n.
$$
Consider the homomorphism
$$
\Phi: G/N \to H, \Phi(gN)=\pi_H(g).
$$
We have
$$
\Phi(gN)=1 \iff\pi_H(g)=1 \iff h=1.
$$
It follows that 
$$
\ker\Phi=\{g=hn\in G: h=1\}=N.
$$

Since every $h \in H$ can be regarded as $h=h\cdot1\in HN=G$, we have 
$$
h=\pi_H(h)=\Phi(hN) \quad \forall h \in H,
$$
i.e. $\Phi$ is surjective. Hence $G/N\cong H$.