# If $I\cong G/H$, where $I$ is a subgroup of $G$, why is $G=IH$?

Tags: group-theory, quotient-group

Maybe I'm missing something simple, but if $I$ is a subgroup of a fixed group $G$, and $H \trianglelefteq G$ is such that $I\cong G/H$, why is it true that $G=IH$? Is this some isomorphism theorem that I'm forgetting how to apply? Thanks.

EDIT: I meant to also add that we know $I\cap H=1$.

Comment: Is $G$ a finite group?

Comment: Not necessarily...

Comment: This came up in Washington's cyclotomic fields book, and I feel like an idiot for not knowing why it's true... Basically, the case I'm looking at is where $G$ is a Galois group of an infinite extension, $I$ is an inertia group, and $H$ is an abelian subgroup of $G$. The author said that $I\cong G/H$, which I'm okay with, but then just says this implies $G=IH$, with no justification.

Comment: I think this is a sort of converse to this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828227/if-g-hn-n-unlhd-g-h-cap-n-1-is-g-n-cong-h?rq=1

Comment: I think it's not true in this generality, unless the isomorphism $I\to G/H$ is the restriction of the quotient map $G\to G/H$, or $G$ is finite.

Comment: Good point: I think that's what I was missing, because then you're right: it follows from the equivalences of inner semidirect product definitions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product

Answer (score 7):

This is false (because you have no assumptions on the isomorphism $I\cong G/H$).

Here's a counterexample: Let $G=\mathbb{Z}$, $H=0$, $I=2\mathbb{Z}$. Then $I$ is abstractly isomorphic to $G/H$ but $G\neq IH$.

However, your question is true if you assume that the isomorphism $I\to G/H$ is given by the composition $I\to G\to G/H$.
In this case, we know that the image of the isomorphism $I\to G/H$ is the subgroup $(IH)/H$.
Thus, $G=IH$.

Your question is also true if you assume that $G$ is finite.
In this case, $\lvert I\rvert=\lvert G/H\rvert=\lvert G\rvert/\lvert H\rvert$ so $\lvert IH\rvert=\frac{\lvert I\rvert\cdot\lvert H\rvert}{\lvert I\cap H\rvert}=\lvert G\rvert.$